# Why do I get non integer results from MILP problem?

Tags: matlab, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I have a matlab script for diet linear programming problem. I am trying to compare results of linearprog or(intlinprog) with results of cplexlp(or cplexmilp) functions provided by toolbox CPLEX for matlab by IBM 
here is the script

```
    %% Defining Variables 
clear;clc
Pnames = ["BEEF";
                    "CHK";
                    "FISH";
                    "HAM";
                    "MCH";
                    "MTL";
                    "SPG";
                    "TUR" ];
Packs = optimvar('Packs',Pnames,'Type','integer');
Packs.LowerBound = 2*ones(length(Pnames),1);
Packs.UpperBound = 10*ones(length(Pnames),1);
%% Setting the problem data
CostPerPack = [3.19;2.59;2.29;2.89;1.89;1.99;1.99;2.49];
VitA = [60;8;8;40;15;70;25;60];
VitC = [20;0;10;40;35;30;50;20];
VitB1 = [10;20;15;35;15;15;25;15];
VitB2 = [15;20;10;10;15;15;15;10];
NA = [938;2180;945;278;1182;896;1329;1397];
CAL = [295;770;440;430;315;400;370;450];
% Amount Per package table
TAMT = table(VitA,VitC,VitB1,VitB2,NA,CAL,...
    'VariableNames',{'A','C','B1','B2','NA','CAL'},...
    'RowNames',Pnames);
%% Objective 
TotCost = sum(CostPerPack .* Packs); % Objective 
obj = TotCost;
%% Constraints 
prob = optimproblem('Objective',obj,'ObjectiveSense','min');
prob.Constraints.c1 = sum(VitA.*Packs) >= 700;
prob.Constraints.c1a = sum(VitA.*Packs) <= 20000;
prob.Constraints.c2 = sum(VitC.*Packs) >= 700;
prob.Constraints.c2a = sum(VitC.*Packs) <= 20000;
prob.Constraints.c3 = sum(VitB1.*Packs) >= 700;
prob.Constraints.c3a = sum(VitB1.*Packs) <= 20000;
prob.Constraints.c4 = sum(VitB2.*Packs) >= 700;
prob.Constraints.c4a = sum(VitB2.*Packs) <= 20000;
prob.Constraints.c5 = sum(NA.*Packs) >= 0;
prob.Constraints.c5a = sum(NA.*Packs) <= 40000;
prob.Constraints.c5 = sum(CAL.*Packs) >= 16000;
prob.Constraints.c5a = sum(CAL.*Packs) <= 24000;
%% Putting the problem together and solving
problem = prob2struct(prob);
% LP
% [sol,fval,exitflag,output1] = linprog(problem);
% [sol2,fval2,exitflag2,output2] = cplexlp(problem);
% MILP problem
[sol,fval,exitflag,output1] = intlinprog(problem);
[sol2,fval2,exitflag2,output2] =cplexmilp(problem);
%% Display 
disp('Linear Prog function results')
if (~isempty(sol) )
T1 = table(sol,sol.*VitA,sol.*VitC,sol.*VitB1,sol.*VitB2,sol.*NA,sol.*CAL,sol.*CostPerPack,...
    'VariableNames',{'NuofPacks','PerVitA','PerVitC','PerVitB1','PerVitB2','NA','CAL','Cost'},...
    'RowNames',Pnames);
sumrow = array2table(sum(T1.Variables),...
    'VariableNames',...
    {'NuofPacks','PerVitA','PerVitC','PerVitB1','PerVitB2','NA','CAL','Cost'},...
    'RowNames',"Sum");
T1 = [T1;sumrow];
disp(T1)
else
    disp(['No feasible Solution with exit flag = ' ,num2str(exitflag)])
end
%% Display Cplex
disp('Cplex function results')
if (~isempty(sol2) )
T2 = table(sol2,sol2.*VitA,sol2.*VitC,sol2.*VitB1,sol2.*VitB2,sol2.*NA,sol2.*CAL,sol2.*CostPerPack,...
    'VariableNames',{'NuofPacks','PerVitA','PerVitC','PerVitB1','PerVitB2','NA','CAL','Cost'},...
    'RowNames',Pnames);
sumrow2 = array2table(sum(T2.Variables),...
    'VariableNames',...
    {'NuofPacks','PerVitA','PerVitC','PerVitB1','PerVitB2','NA','CAL','Cost'},...
    'RowNames',"Sum");
T2 = [T2;sumrow2];
disp(T2)
else
    disp(['No feasible Solution with exit flag = ' ,num2str(exitflag2)])
end
```

and here Cplex function results

```
NuofPacks    PerVitA    PerVitC    PerVitB1    PerVitB2     NA       CAL       Cost 
        _________    _______    _______    ________    ________    _____    ______    ______

BEEF          2         120         40          20        30        1876       590      6.38
CHK          10          80          0         200       200       21800      7700      25.9
FISH          2          16         20          30        20        1890       880      4.58
HAM           2          80         80          70        20         556       860      5.78
MCH          10         150        350         150       150       11820      3150      18.9
MTL          10         700        300         150       150        8960      4000      19.9
SPG      7.3333      183.33     366.67      183.33       110        9746    2713.3    14.593
TUR           2         120         40          30        20        2794       900      4.98
Sum      45.333      1449.3     1196.7      833.33       700       59442     20793    101.01
```

The reults for this MILP from intlinprog seems good but from cplexmilp I get non-ineger value for SPG package. 
Can anyone help me to know the problem here ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check whether you marked your integer variables as integer for `cplexmilp()`.? Can you export the LP file from `cplexmilp` (see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/cplexoptimset-m.html for how to do it) and check whether variables are marked integer there.

Comment: I am trying the following : 
problem.options = cplexoptimset ('ExportModel','LP232.mod')
cplexmilp(problem)
but I get the following error 
Error using cplexmilp
CPLEX Error  1424: Invalid filetype.

I am not sure about the filetype should I provide

Comment: The extension of the file must not be `.mod` but `.lp`.

Comment: I have exported it. I didn't find a clue that variables are declared as integers. 
here is a snap from the file : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vggo0Nje6jlhpJQWwmMMNKWxgeK2Oy_J/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following: when you call `problem = prob2struct(prob);` the integrality information from `prob` is carried over into `problem.intcon`, but unfortunately it is not carried over into cplex.

This issue came up before, but was not addressed directly in cplex since there is a trivial workaround: replace the call

```
[sol2,fval2,exitflag2,output2] =cplexmilp(problem);
```

with

```
[sol2,fval2,exitflag2,output2] = ...
    cplexmilp(problem.f, problem.Aineq, problem.bineq, problem.Aeq, ...
              problem.beq, [], [], [], problem.lb, problem.ub, ...
              intcon_ctype(length(problem.lb),problem.intcon));
```

where the intcon_ctype function is:

```
function ctype = intcon_ctype(numvars, intcon)
   ctype = char(ones(1, numvars) * 'C');
   for i = 1:length(intcon)
      ctype(intcon(i)) = 'I'
   end
end
```

Note that this is a very simplistic `intcon_ctype` conversion function. You may want to check the lb/ub values and set the type to 'B' if the variable is binary, you can specify semi-continuous variables, etc.

Comment: This is working as expected. Thank you. Any ideas why did not integrality carried over cplex?